# Erlang - checking for existence of dynamic variable retrieved from JSON path

Tags: json, erlang, tsung

I am trying to retrieve an attribute 'seriesId' from a JSON response. This attribute itself may or may not exist in the response.

```
<dyn_variable name="myseriesId" jsonpath="catalog[0].dummy[0].seriesId"/>
```

So, here I want to do some stuff based on the availability of the above attribute. Below is the code that I tried.

```
<setdynvars sourcetype="eval"
     code="fun({Pid,DynVars})->
            case ts_dynvars:lookup(myseriesId,DynVars) of
                {ok, SeriesId} ->
                      io:format(' seriesId : ~B : ~n',[SeriesId]),
                       BoolSeries = 1;
                 _ ->
                      io:format(' setting bool to zero: ~n'),
                      BoolSeries =0
                 end,
                 BoolSeries
             end.">
         <var name="checkSeries" />
     </setdynvars>
```

I encountered some issues here. I see this in logs.

```
 ts_search:(4:<0.102.0>) Dyn Var: no Match (varname=myseriesId),
 ts_client:(5:<0.102.0>) Stop in state wait_ack, reason= {badarg,
                                                          [{io,
                                                          format,
                                                          [<0.77.0>,
                                                          ' seriesId : ~B : ~n',
                                                            [<<>>]],
                                                            []},
                                                            {erl_eval,
                                                            .....
```

JSON response did not have 'seriesId' attribute, but looks like this code is still hitting 'ok' case. I am confused here.
This code works if JSON response has 'seriesId' attribute.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the log message we can see that the return value of `ts_dynvars:lookup(myseriesId,DynVars)` is `<<>>`, i.e. an empty binary, but you expect it to be an integer (to match the `~B` format specifier).

One thing you could do is adding a guard to the case clause, to make sure it only gets selected if the value is an integer:

```
        case ts_dynvars:lookup(myseriesId,DynVars) of
            {ok, SeriesId} when is_integer(SeriesId) ->
                  io:format(' seriesId : ~B : ~n',[SeriesId]),
...
```

Or you could make another case clause for the case of the empty binary, and deal with it separately.

```
        case ts_dynvars:lookup(myseriesId,DynVars) of
            {ok, <<>>} ->
                  io:format(' setting bool to zero: ~n'),
                  BoolSeries = 0;
            {ok, SeriesId} ->
                  io:format(' seriesId : ~B : ~n',[SeriesId]),
                   BoolSeries = 1;
...
```

Comment: Thank you!!          `2417- fatal: unexpected_char
Config Error, aborting ! {fatal,
                             {unexpected_char,`  - {ok, <<>>} -> seems to be causing issues for me. Can you help?

Comment: Right, since the Erlang code gets inserted into an XML file, you need to escape the `<` and `>` characters. Instead of `{ok, <<>>}`, write `{ok, &lt;&lt;&gt;&gt;}`.